# Predicate<T> и Func<string> в качестве T

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть List< Func< string>> нужно вызвать List.RemoveAll().Туда нужно передать Predicate< T>. нужно удалить только определнные функции. На MSDN Видел пример с Point, но попытка переделать аналогично под Func не получается. В чем проблема?

```
    List<Func<string>> _list;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        _list = new List<Func<string>>();
        _list.Add(this.test);
        _list.Add(this.test2);
        _list.Add(this.test);
        _list.Add(this.test2);
        _list.Add(this.test);

        Predicate<Func<string>> pre = ValidateFunc(test2,nameof(test2));// тут функция и подчеркивается с ошибкой
    }

    private static bool ValidateFunc(Func<string> obj,string targetName)
    {
        return targetName == nameof(obj);
    }

    string test()
    {
        textBox.Text += " 2";
        return "";
    }
    string test2()
    {
        textBox.Text += " 3";
        return "";
    }
```

Ошибка:Не удается неявно преобразовать тип "bool" в "System.Predicate< System.Func< string>>"

Если как на MSDN без параметров то ошибка такая: Нет перегруженного метода для "ValidateFunc", который соответствует делегату "Predicate< Func< string>>"

Comment: У вас ValidateFunc возвращает булево значение, и вы явно его вызываете. Какое поведение вы ожидаете?

Comment: @Etki, Я добавил какую ошибку выдает без явного вызова.
Необходимо что бы удалялись указанные функции из List.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я предлагаю такой вариант:

```
Predicate<Func<string>> pre = item => item == this.test;
```

В частности, при использовании этого предиката в качестве аргумента метода `_list.RemoveAll`, из коллекции `_list` будут удалены все вхождения метода `test`.

Либо так, если вместо ссылки на метод вы желаете использовать строку с именем метода:

```
Predicate<Func<string>> pre = item => item.Method.Name == "test";
```

*А назначение вашего метода `ValidateFunc` мне понять не удалось. Вы в нем сравниваете строку `targetName` с `nameof(obj)` (то есть со строковой константой `"obj"`).*

Comment: В targetName задавалось строковой вид функции, дабы использовать функцию динамично(а не для отдельной функции). Указать нужный обьект и указать чему он должен был быть равен. Я не успел ешё дойти то этого момента из за возникшей проблемы

Answer (score 1):

Ответ @DmitryD самый полезный для моего решения.
То, чего необходимо было добиться выглядит так:

```
    List<Func<string>> _list;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        _list = new List<Func<string>>();
        _list.Add(this.test);
        _list.Add(this.test2);

        _list.RemoveAll(getpredicate(test2));
    }

    static public Predicate<Func<string>> getpredicate(Func<string> obj)
    {
        Predicate<Func<string>> pre2 = item => item == obj;
        return pre2;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Во первых, ValidateFunc должен выглядеть следующим образом

```
private static bool ValidateFunc(Func<string> obj);
```

Только один параметр.

Во вторых, Вам @Etki сделал корректное замечание, Вы неправильно инициализируете свой `Predicate<Func<string>> pre`, Вы там вызываете Вашу функцию ValidateFunc, а надо так:

```
Predicate<Func<string>> pre = new Predicate<Func<string>>(ValidateFunc);
```

Ну и конечно, как нужно было код написать целиком:

```
List<Func<string>> _list;
public MainWindow()
{
    _list = new List<Func<string>>();
    _list.Add(this.test);
    _list.Add(this.test2);
    _list.Add(this.test);
    _list.Add(this.test2);
    _list.Add(this.test);

    Predicate<Func<string>> pre = new Predicate<Func<string>>(ValidateFunc);

    _list.RemoveAll(pre);
}

private static bool ValidateFunc(Func<string> obj)
{
    return "test2" == obj.Method.Name;
}

string test()
{
    textBox.Text += " 2";
    return "";
}
string test2()
{
    textBox.Text += " 3";
    return "";
}
```

Ну и вариант решения с помощью лямбда функции:

```
List<Func<string>> _list;
public MainWindow()
{
    _list = new List<Func<string>>();
    _list.Add(this.test);
    _list.Add(this.test2);
    _list.Add(this.test);
    _list.Add(this.test2);
    _list.Add(this.test);

   _list.RemoveAll(f => f.Method.Name == "test2");
}


string test()
{
    textBox.Text += " 2";
    return "";
}
string test2()
{
    textBox.Text += " 3";
    return "";
}
```

Comment: То что там должен быть 1 праметр я уже догадался.
Predicate<Func<string>> pre = new Predicate<Func<string>>(ValidateFunc); не обязателен. работет и мой вариант Predicate<Func<string>> pre = ValidateFunc; не думаю что MSDN на столько бы ошиблась.

Comment: @BwehaaFox, так у Вас там написано не `pre = ValidateFunc;`, а `pre = ValidateFunc(test2,nameof(test2));`, то есть в pre Вы записываете `bool`.

Comment: я в комментарии под основным постом написал что я проверил и без параметров.

Comment: @BwehaaFox, у Вас ошибка была из-за несоответствия количества параметров, о чём я Вам написал в начале своего ответа.

Comment: Ну так а я лишь прокомментировал момент с инициализацией предиката, о том что записывать его не обязательно так длинно, и представленный мною короткий вариант никак не влиял на проблему.